# How to add "or" in pathsubst in Makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have mixers of c and c++ source files . I am trying to combine them to .o's required for target directory.

```
SOURCES: = SOURCES=src/test.c src/cpptest.cpp src/directfb_test.cpp src/foo.c
```

What I tried:

```
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:src/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
OBJECTS+=$(SOURCES:src/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
```

and this also

```
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(notdir $(SOURCES))))
OBJECTS += $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(notdir $(SOURCES))))
```

Both doesn't seem to be working.

I get both .o's as well as .c and .cpps in OBJECTS . Is there a way to add OR in patsubst ?

Solution:

```
   OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o,$(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(filter %.cpp  ,$(notdir $(SOURCES)) )) )
   OBJECTS += $(patsubst %.c, %.o,$(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(filter %.c ,$(notdir $(SOURCES)) )) )
```

Added filter for %.c and %.cpp . I guess there will be other ways . I am going with this.

Comment: Erm... since the rule to turn `.c` and `.cpp` *into* object files differ (C vs. C++ compiler), why bother?

Comment: @DevSolar Yes the rule is different . The real problem came from this           $(LD) -r -o $@ -X $(wildcard $(OBJDIR)/*.o) . This takes all the .o files from obj dir instead of picking up only the necessary ones.

Comment: And Only C++ compiler is used in this case.

Comment: So you don't actually need *one* list of objects: `$(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ -X $(COBJECTS) $(CPPOBJECTS)`...

Comment: that is one way of solving it.

Comment: You *need* a list of only the C sources (for the C compiler rule), and you *need* a list of only the C++ sources (for the C++ compiler rule). Wherever you need the contents of both lists, just give both lists as shown in my previous comment; you don't need that in a variable. Also, note that it makes quite some difference whether you `+=` to a variable defined with `=` (your first example), or `:=` (your second example). Check https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Appending. I think you're barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: @DevSolar thanks for pointing out the difference between := and = , =+ applied . Makefile implicitly follows pattern matching rule if there are same target with diffrent pre-requisite .http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match . In this case %.o: %.c and %.o:%.cpp will be sufficient. But as you mentioned if it is two separate list it will be more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the fastest to process and easiest to understand is

```
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %c, $(OBJDIR)/%o, $(patsubst %pp, %, $(notdir $(SOURCES))))
```

Comment: I guess my approach is safest . what will happen if the src directory contains some .h files in it ? In that case your approach may fail.

Comment: @Knight71: How do you figure? I don't see why this - not really clean as it is, but anyway - would fail for `.h` files in the source directory. Unless, of course, you'd list them in `SOURCES`, which would be somewhat... erm... buggy?

Comment: Knight71, my approach is exactly equivalent to yours, except it eliminates several unnecessary steps: I have 1 notdir and 2 patsubst, you have 2 notdir, 2 filter, 2 addprefix, and 2 patsubst. Anotheer reason why I do it that way, is to emphasize that cpp sources are from a language evolved from c, so we first reduce cpp sources to c sources.

Comment: @MarkGaleck: I agree with you that this is better and efficient than mine.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is:

```
OBJECTS := $(patsubst src/%.cpp, $(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SOURCES))
OBJECTS := $(patsubst src/%.c, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(OBJECTS))
```

If you want to know what's wrong with the first to approaches in the question, just put `$(info $(OBJECTS))` between the two commands, and it'll be pretty clear.

Comment: Well, I am assuming that he uses "notdir" for a reason, that not all sources may be in "src" dir.